# How to implement this logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using javascript in my project and i am a newbie. I have a scenario where i want to implement a Status property for my component. This Status property show the current status of my component out of a list of available status. For example:

*I implemented in this way:*

```
  var availableStatus = [
                          { Name: 'visible' }, 
                          { Name: 'hidden' }, 
                          { Name: 'deny' }, 
                          { Name: 'allow' }, 
                          { Name: 'destroy' }
                         ];

  var Status = availableStatus[0];

  if(Status === availableStatus[0])
    //do this 
  else if(Status === availableStatus[1])
    //do this 
  ...
```

But i feel that there should be some another better approach for this. And this logic is dependent on array items order which may create problem in future if array order changes. I have another logic for implement this by using Named Array. But i dont know how.

Please can anyone give me a better suggestion to implement this kind of scenario ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index them by their name (if that is sufficiently unique):

```
var availableStatus = {
                      visible : { Name: 'visible' }, 
                      hidden : { Name: 'hidden' }, 
                      deny : { Name: 'deny' }, 
                      allow : { Name: 'allow' }, 
                      destroy : { Name: 'destroy' }
                     };

var Status = availableStatus.visible;

if(Status === availableStatus.visible)
    //do this 
else if(Status === availableStatus.hidden)
    //do this
```

This is assuming that there is some more information in the status objects later on, or functions working on that data. If you just want to store a string you can just do it like this:

```
var availableStatus = {
                      visible : {},
                      hidden : {}, 
                      deny : {}, 
                      allow : {}, 
                      destroy : {}
                     };
```

and have the same functionality.

Comment: This is what I do, effectively like a JavaScript 'enum' replacement

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use a `switch` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.

```
switch(Status) {
  case 'visible':
    // do something...
    break;
  case 'hidden':
    // do something else...
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, as `Status` is not a `string`. You might want to use `Status.Name` instead...

Answer (score 0):

How about that? You can store more information in the dictionary assigned to the status, e.g. "can_recieve_messages".

```
    var availableStatus = {
                          'visible': { id: 0 }, 
                          'hidden':  { id: 1},
                          'deny' : { id: 2} [...]
                         };

    var Status = availableStatus.visible;

    switch (Status ) {
        case availableStatus.visible:
           // on visible
           break;
        case availableStatus.hidden:
           // on hidden
           break;
      [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var availableStatus ={};

                        availableStatus.['visible']='visible';
                        availableStatus.['hidden']= 'hidden';
                        availableStatus.['deny']= 'deny';
                        availableStatus.['deny']= 'deny' ; 
                        availableStatus.['destroy']= 'destroy';
```

i have st key name as same as value you can use any name for key and value

```
   availableStatus.['test']= 'deny' ;
```

and you can use anything without the fear of order
if you write **availableStatus.destroy** then out put will **destroy**

and   **availableStatus.test** then output will be  **deny**